# How to Add rows to DataGrid containing a combox column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid is defined as follows:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,39,0,0" Name="DataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="277">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" />
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Value" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

How can I bind a list of strings to the DataGrid and include items "Yes", "No", "Maybe" to the DataGridComboboxColumn for each row?

```
var fruit new List<string> {"Apple","Orange","Banana"};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Fruit
{
    public string ID {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

**XAML**

```
  <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="myGrid" Margin="10">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>                
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="100" x:Name="Result" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Result, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Result}"></DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

**Code-behind**

```
public partial class DataGridComboBox : Window
{
    public List<Fruits> Fruits { get; set; }
    public List<string> Result{ get; set; }

    public DataGridComboBox()
    {
        Fruits  = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee() { Name = "Apple", Result= "Yes" },
            new Employee() { Name = "Mango",Result = "No" },
            new Employee() { Name = "Banana",Result ="MayBe" }
        };

        Result= new List<string>();
        Result.Add("Yes");
        Result.Add("No");
        Result.Add("MayBe");
        InitializeComponent();
        myGrid.ItemsSource = Fruits;
        Result.ItemsSource = Result;
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan, that's helped get me closer to my end goal.

Comment: @matinau can you mark it as an answer if it has helped you

Answer (score 0):

```
<wpf:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="SizeToHeader" IsReadOnly="True" Header="First Selection">
    <wpf:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding .}"
            Margin="2,0,2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </wpf:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

You can use template column to add checkbox in datagrid